# Finding a drive name...not the drive letter...with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a requirement in a batch file to copy archived files to a specific drive **name**...not letter.
I need to support the drive having different drive letters assigned as it is installed, removed, and moved around. I want to be able to find the drive by its unique name, so that I can then reference the appropriate drive letter for that drive.

This is the closest code I could find on the forum:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:=" %%a in (`wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName^="BACKUP2" get caption /value`) do set drive=%%a:
if "%drive%"=="" (
 echo not inserted
) else (cls
 echo inserted as %drive%
)
```

Which produces "inserted as "BACKUPS2" GET caption /value:" as the output. I was expecting the return of only the drive letter.

In doing my due diligence, I looked at /? for wmic which listed LOGICALDISK as an alias. The wmic help directed me to "switch-alias /?" for help on the alias, but both "LOGICALDISK /?" and "switch-LOGICALDISK /?' report that neither is recognized as an internal or external command....yada, yada.

I note that wmic /? says that wmic is deprecated. Don't know if that affects documentation being available. I also note that the code listed above to find the drive name..not letter...is pretty old.

I'm stuck. If anyone can pull my head out, or suggest an alternate solution, I'd appreciate the effort.

Comment: Tried and tried to insert the code properly but couldn't get it to go.

Comment: `vol` don't help you? `vol /?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unsure about using the deprecated WMIC.exe utility, there are others you can use, and those may be just a little bit quicker too.

You could try this idea using `vol`:

```sh
@SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@For /L %%G In (68, 1, 90) Do @(%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C Exit /B %%G
    Vol !=ExitCodeAscii!: 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:" BACKUP2$" 1>NUL && Copy /Y "C:\MyDir\*" !=ExitCodeAscii!:\)
```

Alternatively you could use `fsutil.exe`, *(which may, on some Operating Systems, require to be 'Run as administrator')*:

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\fsutil.exe FSInfo Drives 2^>NUL') Do @For %%I In (%%H) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\fsutil.exe FSInfo VolumeInfo %%~dI | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:" : BACKUP2$" 1>NUL && Copy /Y "C:\MyDir\*" "%%I"
```

*Obviously you'd change `"C:\MyDir\*"` to your actual source file glob and add further branches the the destination root directory; *(`!=ExitCodeAscii!:\` in the first example, and `%%I` in the second)* as needed.*

---

**[EDIT /]**

If, as you've implied, you need administrator access for your backup drive, you can probably do this simpler directly in the Administrator Command Prompt window using DiskPart.

```sh
for /f "tokens=3" %g in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart.exe ^| find.exe /i " backup2 "') do @copy /y "c:\mydir\*" "%g:\"
```

If you wanted to do this as administrator from a batch file still, then change it to:

```sh
@for /f "tokens=3" %%g In ('echo list volume ^| diskpart.exe ^| find.exe /i " backup2 "') do @copy /y "c:\mydir\*" "%%g:\"
```

Comment: Well, yes...obviously :) I apologize, but I'm over my head. I had to look up "glob", and found it was a lump of semiliquid substance as in thick globs of melted mozzarella cheese. I looked in my computer, but didn't see any. Now you can see why my nic is RocketSurgeon and not RocketScientist. I'll keep pushing the rope from this end...thanks for your help.

Comment: Some people call them wildcard patterns, `*.pdf`, `*.*`, `*.jp?g` etc are globs, my answer uses `*` as a single wildcard character, and advises that you may wish to replace the `C:\MyDir\*` glob it is part of. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) for more information.

Comment: If you want to just see what the command in my code does, _(how it looks)_, instead of running it, change `&& Copy` to `&& Echo Copy`, and run that script without any other modification.

Comment: I was just kidding, except for the part where I admitted that it was over my head. I actually found the same Wikipedia page explaining globs, but thanks for providing it. While I don't fully understand your script, it seems to be copying a file, which I have not asked about. I want to provide the name of a disk...not the letter...and have the only return be the drive letter. Apologies if I simply don't understand.

Comment: I made the change as suggested, but the output hasn't changed; "The system cannot find...." There is a space following the RIC:" text, is that supposed to be there? Is the drive name tolerant of spaces in the name? I confirmed that the drive are shared.

Comment: For some reason I now get no response. After a pause it returns to the cmd window cursor C:>

Comment: Based upon your last but one comment regarding administrator access, I've added another possibility to my answer post for you to try @RocketSurgeon.

Comment: Compo: your last version worked perfectly. With a minor modification, its doing in one line what I was hacking together with a couple of dozen lines of ugly code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I play a Brain Scientist on TV.

```
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%G IN ('wmic logicaldisk where volumename^="BACKUP2" get caption /format:csv') DO SET "drive=%%G"
```

Comment: :) Note that a Brain Scientist actually exists, while a Rocket Surgeon is a dipshit...thats ME! It appears so far that the Mapping of a non-network drive, in my case a USB docking station, requires a little research. Thank you for your response. I'll go to school on it and see if I can learn something.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm doing something wrong. First of all let me say I am revisiting batch files after 20 years of absence, so please bear with me. I replaced the volume name with a volume that I know exists on my system...located in a USB docking station. I'm getting the message "The system cannot find the path specified." I've verified the spelling of the drive name. I tried to get the target path by adding the line "echo %drive% and get the same message.

Comment: @RocketSurgeon the code works fine on all my computers. Could you just execute that single line of code I gave you in a batch file.  Open up a command prompt and execute the batch file from the command line.  Then show me the output from everything.

Comment: I opened a new window with administrator privileges and your line above is working well...thanks. How would I know it was working if I had not added the echo %drive% line to see the resultant drive? I looked up the docs for wmic logicaldisk online but saw no form that included "volumename^=" as you used. Do you have a source that documents that usage? edit: I opened another cmd window without admistrator privlidges, and it works fine. I don't know what the problem was.

Comment: I removed my added echo and the output is:   SET "drive=G:

Comment: I don't know how to show you the output.

Comment: Your code also uses `volumename^=`. I assumed you understood why the carrot was being used. The equals symbol is a command delimeter. When it is not quoted it must be escaped inside the command block of the `FOR` command

Comment: Squashman: Aahhh, Ok, thanks for the explanation, and your kind assistance. It is very much appreciated.